# Waf configuration in ns-3

Tags: c++, waf, ns-3

I am using the waf script in order to build the ns-3 simulator. I also installed (I mean I have downloaded and built the openflow module of the ns-3 simulator.) However when I want to include a header file of the openflow module (which is located in a different directory of the linux) to a class of one of another module (e.g. lte module) in original ns-3 source code , I get no such file or directory error. I tried to change the wafscript by adding the path of the header file that i would like to add but it didn't work. What else can i try to fix that problem?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found the problem.It has turned out that this is an error caused by the configuration file of the corresponding wscript file (wscript file of lte module). In this file I needed to add up the openflow module as a source module of the lte module by modifying build method like

```
  module = bld.create_ns3_module('lte', ['<another modules>','openflow'])
```

With that way now the waf build system is able to include the openflow module as a source path.